# e-texteditor go to last active tab doesn't work

Tags: tabs, e-texteditor

I checked the option in the settings, but still clicking CTRL-TAB once does not go to the last active tab. I tried restarting the editor but to no avail.

my e-texteditor version is 1.0.43

This is really really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fixed in new 2.0 version.

Comment: No it's not. there's still an open issue on this.
http://www.e-texteditor.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=15757#15757